# Qt Quick application running from command line

Tags: qt, qt-quick

While I am trying to run Qt Quick desktop application exe from command line, it is not showing anything except an plain empty window. But when I run from Qt creator, it works fine.

Please let me know did I missed something? How to run Qt Quick projects from command line?

Thanks,
BR

Comment: How do you load the main QML file ? Did you create the project from the QtCreator wizard ?

Comment: Yes , I will create a project from QtCreator and I will load QML from main.cpp with   viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/qml/positioners.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded(); ..

Comment: Make sure your are not specifying qml path wrongly!!It seems like the path you given in setMainFile is relative to running directory of QtCreator.